# python subprocess call not doing anything

Tags: android, python, terminal, subprocess

I am creating a GUI to launch various applications from the click of a button. To save me from having to open them all up manually.

I am currently trying to launch an Android emulator, I can do this with the following command: `emulator @Nexus_5X_API_22` ...pretty simple.

I am trying to do this in python using:
`subprocess.Popen(["emulator @Nexus_5X_API_22"],shell = True)`

However, nothing seems to happen when this is called. A print statement returns '127', not sure what that infers?

What am I doing wrong?

-----------EDIT-----------

here is some code, I am using Kivy.

```
class RunTests(Screen):
def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super(RunTests,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    layout1 = StackLayout(orientation='lr-bt')

    runbutton = Button(text='run all', size_hint=(0.8,0.05))
    runbutton.bind(on_press=self.runAll)

    layout1.add_widget(runbutton)

    self.add_widget(layout1)

def runAll(self,*args):
    subprocess.Popen(["emulator", "@Nexus_5X_API_22"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't separate the parameters into separate items in the list. Because you said "shell=True", subprocess tried to run a program called `"emulator\ @Nexux_5X_API_22"`. Separate out the parameters and skip the shell

```
subprocess.Popen(["emulator", "@Nexus_5X_API_22"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so @Youn Elan suggested using the full path.

```
subprocess.Popen(['/Users/User/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_22'],shell=True)
```

this does work.